# Changing the previous command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Is there a way to change the previous command in linux? I'm copying a bunch of files using

```
cp path/to/source1 path/to/target2
```

and I want to change it to

```
cp path/to/source2 path/to/target2
```

so I want to replace the 1 with the 2

I know I can put this inside a loop but I need to do this after checking something in my notebook.

Comment: what do you mean by "change the command"? can you please explain it other way?

Comment: You may use the 'read' command to pause the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
!!:gs/1/2/
```

Here are some more examples:
http://mark.stosberg.com/Tech/tips/bash.tips

Comment: Great! Is there a way to change a command which wasn't the last?

Comment: Not in a clean way that I know of, no.

Comment: afaik you can use instead of !! also !-n where n is the number of previously line you want. !! is nothing else than !-1.

Answer (score 2):

the command for this manipulation of history is:

```
^old-text^new-text
```

For more reading I can just recommend the man page of bash, esp. the parts of readline and history.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to change a command that is not the last? Also, this change only the first occurance of old-text

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you do this in a command line, not in bash script
the quickest way is to write `cp` and PRESS `Alt+.`, `press space`, and Press `Alt+.` again and repair the path

`Alt+.` gives you last parameter you used

`Ctrl+R` gives you reverse search

`UP arrow` gives you latest commands

Answer (score 0):

press the up arrow to get the last command, then change whatever you want to have different.

or if you want to address an older command hit 'Ctrl-r' then start typing what you want and if the correct old command appears hit right arrow to make it the current. Then change whatever you want to change.